# Switch between InteractionRequests

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a viewModel with several interactionRequests. The code for each interactionRequest is essentially the same, only the calling functions changes e.g:

```
this.SimpleRequest.Raise(new SimpleViewModel() { Title = "Simple" },
(vm) => 
{
    if(vm.ConfirmationResult)
        doSomething(vm);
}

this.ExtendedRequest.Raise(new ExtendedViewModel() { Title = "Simple" },
(vm) => 
{
    if(vm.ConfirmationResult)
        doSomething(vm);
}
```

Is there a way such that i can dynamically insert the function instead of writing the same codeblock over and over for each request?

Comment: Does ExtendedViewModel inherit from SimpleViewModel?

Comment: No they are completely separate. They both inherit from Prism.Notification though.